# Having Lists as a value in Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In this code I would like to append a dictionary from a text file with the values of the dictionary as lists. This code only appends the text file into a dictionary with 1 value. How do I make it so that the values are a list and how would I write the text file?

CODE

```
dtablet{}
if device == "tablet":
   for line in ftablet:
      (key,val) = line.split(":")
      dtablet[str(key)] = val
```

TEXT FILE (ftablet)

> model:apple,samsung,sony     <--- I would like the names to be in a list with the key as model
>   apple:iPad1,iPad2,iPad3        <--- I would like the names to be in a list with the key as apple
>   ipad1:16GB,32GB,64GB           <--- I would like the memories to be in a list and the key as ipad1

Thank You

Comment: first line : `dtablet={}`, also try to make complete examples, so the variable device would need to be defined. See e.g. [mcve].

Comment: Is your question: "How can I write to text file?"

Answer (score 1):

After `line.split(":")`,  you got `val` as a string with all values. You must split `val` again to get a list of values

```
dtablet{}
if device == "tablet":
   for line in ftablet:
      (key,val) = line.split(":")
      dtablet[str(key)] = val.split(',')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!!!